# Lightning:TreeGrid | Upon selection of parent rows, child rows doesn't get selected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app

I have a situation where I need to select all child rows in a lightning:treeGrid when parent row gets selected but lightning:treeGrid doesn't provide this behavior, is it a bug? How can I achieve it?
[image]

The behavior can be seen in the picture I have selected the parent but child is still un-selected

Code :

```
<lightning:treeGrid aura:id="ATree" columns="{!v.gridColumnsArt}" data="{!v.gridDataArt}" keyField="id"  onrowselection = "{!c.getSelectedName}"/>
```

Comment: i dont see anywhere in the documentation that this is supposed to work OOTB, looks like you have to set the code yourself to have all children selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with standard functionality of the component.

What you can do to achieve your requirements, is to use the `onrowselection` event:

```
<lightning:treeGrid aura:id="ATree" columns="{!v.gridColumnsArt}" data="{!v.gridDataArt}" keyField="id"  onrowselection = "{!c.getSelectedName}"/>
```

And then get all selected rows:

```
getSelectedName: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
        alert("You selected: " + JSON.stringify(selectedRows[i]));
    }        
},
```

Inside this loop you should select all child nodes of the selected node